# Remove whitespace from part of a string

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

In the following string, how can I remove the spaces inside the parentheses?

```
"The quick brown fox (jumps over the lazy dog)"
```

Desired output:

```
"The quick brown fox (jumpsoverthelazydog)"
```

I'm guessing I need to use regex. I need to target the inside of the parentheses. Following would remove everything in the parentheses including the parentheses.

```
preg_replace("/\(.*?\)/", "", $string)
```

And this doesn't work:

```
preg_replace("/\(\s\)/", "", $string)
```

I admit, regular expression isn't my strong suit. How can I target only the inside of the parentheses?

---

**Note**: Above string is only for demonstration. Actual string and the position of the parentheses vary. Following cases are possible:

```
"The quick brown fox (jumps over the lazy dog)"

"The quick (brown fox jumps) over (the lazy dog)"

"(The quick brown fox) jumps over the lazy dog"
```

---

Using Poiz's answer, I've modifed the code for personal use:

```
function empty_parantheses($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback("<\(.*?\)>", function($match) {
        return preg_replace("<\s*>", "", $match[0]);
    }, $string);
}
```

Comment: Can parentheses be nested? If so, how should that be handled?

Comment: @Chris No, they can't. Only content (string) is inside the parentheses.

Comment: @akinuri Try my source. Worked well for me! https://3v4l.org/Wija8

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn Yes, checking it now. I'll accept yours if there's not a better solution, a single regex maybe (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest work-around would be to use `preg_replace()` within  `preg_replace_callback()` without any looping or separate `replace-functions` as shown below. The advantage is that you could have even more than one group of strings wrapped inside **(parenthesis)** as the example below shows.. and, by the way, you may test it out [here](https://eval.in/611177).

```
<?php

    $str  = "The quick brown fox (jumps over the lazy dog) and (the fiery lion caught it)";

    $str  = preg_replace_callback("#\(.*?\)#", function($match)  {
        $noSpace    = preg_replace("#\s*?#", "", $match[0]);
        return $noSpace;
    }, $str);

    var_dump($str);
    // PRODUCES:: The quick brown fox (jumpsoverthelazydog) and (thefierylioncaughtit)' (length=68)
```

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn    ;-)

Comment: This seems like a better approach. I'll wrap this in a function and modify it a little.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 `preg_` in this case

```
<?php
    $string = "The quick (brown fox jumps) over (the lazy dog)";
    //First preg search all string in ()
    preg_match_all('/\(.(.*?).\)/', $string, $match);
    foreach ($match[0] as $key => $value) {
        $result = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value);
        if(isset($new_string)){
            $new_string = str_replace($value, $result, $new_string);
        }else{
            $new_string = str_replace($value, $result, $string);
        }

    }
    echo $new_string;
?>
```

Result

```
The quick (brownfoxjumps) over (thelazydog)
```

Demo [Demo link](https://3v4l.org/Wija8)

Comment: Is there a difference between `'/\(.*?\)/'` and `'/\(.(.*?).\)/'`? The former also works.

Comment: @akinuri I think it's same. My parameter (.*?) = [brown fox jumps] . And you .*? = [brown fox jumps]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with a single regular expression.

It should be possible to grab the contents of any brackets, preg_replace all spaces and then re-insert into the original string. This is likely to be quite slow if you have to do it a lot.

The best way is the simple way - simply step through the characters of the string, increment a value when you reach a ( and decrement when you reach a ). If the value is 0, add the character to your buffer; otherwise, check if it's a space first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$str = "The quick (brown fox jumps) over (the lazy dog) asfd (asdf)";
$str = explode('(',$str);
$new_string = '';


foreach($str as $key => $part)
{
       //if $part contains '()'
       if(strpos($part,')') !== false) {
             $part = explode(')',$part);
             //add ( and ) to $part, and add the left-over
             $temp_str = '('.str_replace(' ','',$part[0]).')';
             $temp_str .= $part[1];
             $part = $temp_str;  
       }
       //put everything back together:
       $new_string .= $part;
}
```